# I'm searching for a story set on a future Earth in which the most competent individuals are kidnapped(ish) and made to serve as government leaders

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, government

It's been quite a while since I read this -- I'm thinking 1990's but the story could have been from some time before that.  It was definitely a story and not a novel.  The basic premise is that there is some sort of agency that identifies individuals who will be the best leaders and then just goes and gets those people, who then become president, judge, etc. for some term.  No idea of the author or title.

Comment: Maybe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194656/story-about-an-ai-who-selects-the-new-president

Comment: It reminds me a bit of Asimov's "profession"

Comment: This is, quite obviously, a work of fiction!

Comment: It's a fairly familiar trope, eg. Buffy TVS. when Oz an Willow finally meet each other, Deadpool's selection by a shady agency to be a superhero.

Comment: This reminds me, faintly, of John D. MacDonald's *Ballroom of the Skies*.